Jsforce TypeError: Only absolute URLs are supported when trying to create a task
I'm new to salesforce and jsforce so maybe I'm missing something obvious.
I build a routine to create an account, a contact associated with this account and this is working fine.
But when I try to create a tasj and attach it to this contact I'm receiving this error : TypeError: Only absolute URLs are supported
But I don't send any URL to my new Task object.
Here is how I try to create the task:
const testTask= {
AccountId: accountId,
Description: "First connexion",
Status: "Completed",
Subject: "LinkedIn message, answer to post",
TaskSubType: "LinkedIn",
Type: "Call",
}

const newTask = await conn.sobject("Task").create(taskData);

I'm using jsforce v3.2.0
Am I missing something?
Thank you.

In fact it turned out that the instanceUrl I was sending when creating the jsforce connexion was empty...
That's why I was receiving this error.

hi @Fabrice, can you share the connection initialization? I'm trying to create it using oAuth2 options and I'm running into this issue.
